# Scala's .type and Java's .class literal

Tags: java, class, scala, types, language-design

I wonder from a language design perspective why Scala has removed Java's class literal (e. g. `String.class`) and replaced it with `classOf[String]`, but has then added a "type literal" with its Singletons like `Singleton.type` instead of something like `typeOf[Singleton]`?

Comment: Good question. This syntax also prevents us from using class literals in `match`es, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is my rationalization:

**classOf[T]**

`classOf` is defined in `Predef` as a function with this signature:

```
def classOf[T]: Class[T]
```

Although it's implemented by the compiler, using the function syntax is possible *without having to create any special treatment in terms of syntax*. So that's one reason here to consider this option.

The alternative like `String.class` would imply that each class has a companion object with a field `class`. So there are two problems:

1. `class` is a keyword, so that causes a problem where the syntax would require a special case for it
2. if you just create `class A` *without* a companion object, it's would be odd to be able to refer to `A.class`, which would be like accessing the *class* field on the companion `A`.

**A.type:**

On why `typeOf[A]` may be confusing. It looks like a function call, but types don't live in the same world as function results (function results have types, but the type itself only makes sense at compile time). I can ascribe a type to a variable:

```
scala> val a: A.type = A
a: A.type = A$@c21a68
```

I can't assign a type like it's returned by a function:

```
scala> val b = A.type
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but 'type' found.
   val b = A.type
             ^
```

On the other hand types can be member of a object:

```
scala> object A { type type1 = Int }
defined module A

scala> val x: A.type1 = 1
x: A.type1 = 1
```

So it is not a big stretch to have `A.type` refer to the type of object `A`. Note that `.type` aren't used beyond referring to types of singleton objects, so it's not really that frequent.

Comment: A very useful use of `.type` is Scala's `this.type`, especially useful for [chaining method calls](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/02/thistype-for-chaining-method-calls.html), for instance.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is quite consistent. `Singleton.type` is a dependent type of `Singleton`, while `classOf[Class]` is a type parameter to a method.

Consider this:

```
class A {
    class B
}

val a: A = new A
val b: a.B = new a.B
```

The point here is that `.` is used to indicate something that is a member of a value. It may be a `val`, a `var`, a `def` or an `object` and it may also be a `type`, a `class` or a `trait`.

Since a singleton object is a value, then `Singleton.type` is perfectly valid.

On the other hand, a class is *not* an object, so `Class.class` doesn't make sense. `Class` doesn't exist (as a value), so it is not possible to get a member of it. On the other hand, it's definition as `def classOf[T]: Class[T]` is plain Scala code (even if the actual implementation is compiler magic).